# Custom UITableViewCell rounded corners, padding, bgImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I would like to have an effect like this image:

[image: example]

any suggestion ? i'm not able to add space between cell, i'm able to add radius to 4 corners but the bg color exit from the borders showing a rect...

any suggestion ?

should i subclass something?

thanks

Comment: Use a background image?

Comment: Custom `UITableViewCell`. You need to potentially set backgroundview/color of the UITableView to nil/clearColor

Comment: @AaronBrager i have not wondered about it ... i'll try it thanks

Comment: Maybe using a background image for each row and setting clear color background to the table view would do the trick. You may also add some spacing between cells and clear color separators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the table view background a clear-color view. Make the cell background view an image view containing an image, smaller than the cell and centered, showing the round-rect shape (which can be constructed in code).

I do that here (but my table background is not clear, and the image is not *much* smaller than the cell):

[image]

Comment: ok i'm using an image view to show my image with vg-image, now i have a new problem, when i scroll down my tableview it scroll automatically up and cover my last 2 cell, no idea why it's doing this... any help ? maybe is not reading my row height ? @matt

Comment: total height of cell is greater than total height of my uitableview, any suggestion ? thanks @matt